# How to save a string/character value in progress 4gl/openedge

Tags: character, openedge

in the trigger save button, i applied a syntax

```
field-name = CAPS(var).
```

my question is,how do i save set a specific word(s)/character/phrase in my field-name?

```
WORDS WORDS WORDS **iPHONE** WORDS WORDS WORDS
```

Answer (score 1):

For Progress OpenEdge, there's two ways to change the field's screen value - either display something on the field, or set the field's "SCREEN-VALUE" attribute, like so:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE chField AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.

DEFINE FRAME f-demo
   chField FORMAT "X(10)"
   WITH OVERLAY TITLE "Demo Frame".

ON VALUE-CHANGED OF chField
   DO:

       /* Moves data from the screen field to the variable     */

   ASSIGN chField.

       /* Upper Case the field     */

   ASSIGN chField = CAPS(chField).

       /* One way to change the screen value     */

   DISPLAY chField WITH FRAME f-demo.

       /* Another way to change the screen value */

   ASSIGN chField:SCREEN-VALUE = chField.

   END.

   /* Activate the input   */

UPDATE chField WITH FRAME f-demo.
```

If this doesn't answer your question, you'll need to clarify what you're looking for.

Comment: Let me rephrase.. for example, in the editor box, the value is "THE QUICK BROWSE FOX JUMPED OVER THE LAZY DOG AND THE FOX HAS AN IPHONE ON HIS PAW.", in other row of data, the value is "I HAVE A NEW IPHONE."  I would like the `I` from `IPHONE` to become `iPHONE` automatically when saving. Is this possible?

Comment: Use LOOKUP() to see if there's a specific word you want to change, and ENTRY() = chNewValue to set it.